# How to debug coffeescript in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, visual-studio-code

I don't understand, how I should config launch.json file. For example for debug nodejs-scripts, I just changing configurations.program path, then pressing F5 and all works fine, but what to do with coffee-scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know VSCode.

But you could run the coffe-script compiler in watch mode and generate map files, then debug the generated javascript:

```
coffee -c -m -w coffe_source_folder/
```

Answer (score 0):

because sourcemap, coffee just like js. anyway here is my launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${file}", //important, make sure debug current file
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/dist/api/api.js" //important, where to find sourcemap js file
        ]
    }]
}
```